# selenium locate two the same controls

Tags: c#, javascript, selenium, clone

Here are two links named NEW.

```
< a href="#" onclick="CloneDiv('#Div1');return false;" class="smaller">NEW</a>

< a href="#" onclick="CloneDiv('#Div2');return false;" class="smaller">NEW</a>
```

The difference between them is the onclick action.

One clones a div named Div1.
The other clones a div named Div2.

How do I locate the link that clones Div1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `"//a[@onclick='CloneDiv('#Div2');return false;']"` as your locator